# How do you increase a radio button size

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I'm not new to C# but I am new to XAML/MVVM.

I am developing an application for a touchscreen. It has a number of radio buttons but I need them to be bigger so that when someone touches them they are checked.

I don't mind if the area surrounding the radio button sets the check or if the radio button's actual size is increased.

This is my radio button code. There are about 20 of these so the least amount of code possible would be best.

```
<RadioButton HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" GroupName="History" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Command="{Binding HealthQuestionsTrue}" CommandParameter="MedicalHistory"></RadioButton>
<RadioButton HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" GroupName="History" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3" Command="{Binding HealthQuestionsFalse}" CommandParameter="MedicalHistory"></RadioButton>
```

Comment: Use it in viewbox

Comment: @Lithium I hadn't found that question but it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign an id to it and adjust the size in css or if they will all be changed in the same way assign a cssclass and likewise change in css.

e.g.

```
<RadioButton ID="Button1 "HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" GroupName="History" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Command="{Binding HealthQuestionsTrue}" CommandParameter="MedicalHistory"></RadioButton>

<RadioButton CSSClass="buttons" "HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" GroupName="History" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Command="{Binding HealthQuestionsTrue}" CommandParameter="MedicalHistory"></RadioButton>
```

and the css would be

```
#Button1{
    width:50px;
}
```

OR

```
.buttons{
    width:50px;
}
```